# u-substitution yields a different answer

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

When I compute the indefinite integral of ln(x + x^2), I get 2 answers from 2 different methods.

First method: integration by parts => u-substitution 
Answer = xln(x + x^2) - 2 (x + 1) + ln l x + 1 l + C

Second method: integration by parts => long division
Answer = xln(x + x^2) - 2x + ln l x + 1 l + C

I think both are correct, since they only differ by a constant term. Do I get the same mark in exam if I give either of those?

Comment: Here's how to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$-2(x+1) \ + \ c$  can be written as $-2x -2+c = -2x +c'$ where $c'$ is another constant and in the ***indefinite integral constants may vary as it represents a family of curves***.

And, yes both are equivalent.